# Why does it work?

Tags: python, string, printing, concatenation, fizzbuzz

So I'm learning Python and working through a list of program ideas. Of course I wrote the obligatory FizzBuzz, which worked, but was basically if elif else blablabla. I googled it to see if there are other ways and found this dank one-liner:

```
for i in range(1,101): 
    print("Fizz" * (i % 3 == 0) + "Buzz" * (i % 5 == 0) or i)
```

There are no ifs, no elifs, nothing. I googled "string concatenation" and found info on the * symbol, but don't understand how it's working in this case. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are no ifs, no elifs, nothing.

Sure there are! Just disguised. Looking for string concatenation (i.e. `+`) won't help you, because `*` is *repetition*. Specifically, string `*` n gives you a string that is n copies of string in a row. Further, a boolean value can be implicitly converted to an integer: `True` becomes `1` and `False` becomes `0`. So

```
"Fizz" * (i % 3 == 0)
```

means "One `Fizz` if `i % 3 == 0`, none if not." Same with `Buzz`.

Finally, that `or i` at the end means that if you got the empty string because both parts came up empty, then you get `i` instead. `or` really means "the value of the left hand side unless the left hand side is a false value, in which case return the value of the right hand side."

This trick gets used elsewhere, too. Python doesn't have a direct equivalent to C's `?:` operator, but you can get close to one with a two-element tuple and an index operation because of the bool-to-integer conversion I mentioned above. So C's

```
a? b: c
```

which means "`b` if `a` is true, otherwise `c`" becomes this in Python:

```
(c, b)[a]
```

Comment: The Python equivalent of the ternary operator is `b if a else c`.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to print the string `"Buzz"`  either once `if (i % 5 == 0)` is True or return `i`:

```
In [5]: "foo" * 2
Out[5]: 'foofoo'

In [6]: "foo" * 3
Out[6]: 'foofoofoo'

In [7]: i = 5
In [8]: "foo" *  (i % 5 == 0) or i
Out[9]: 'foo'  
In [9]: "foo" *  (i % 5 == 1) or i
Out[22]: 5
```

The same logic applies to "Fizz" sometimes `(i % 3 == 0)` will be True so we see it once, when it is False we don't see it.

When you use the `*` operator on a string it will repeat the string `n` times, in this case it will once at most as either string is only printed based on the result of the boolean test.

You can see in ipython exactly what happens with `True` and `False`:

```
In [26]: "foo" * True
Out[26]: 'foo'

In [27]: "foo" * False
Out[27]: ''
```

Basically `True * "foo"` is equivalent to `1 * "foo"` `"foo" * False` is equivalent to `0 * "foo"`

Bool is a subclass of int so the code is taking advantage of that fact, you sometimes see similar logic used with indexing a list based on a test although not recommended:

```
In [31]: d = ["bar","foo"]   
In [32]: d[3<2] # False so we get 0 the first element
Out[32]: 'bar'   
In [33]: d[3>2] # True so we get 1 the second element
Out[33]: 'foo'
```

Comment: Actually, the multipliers are boolean.

Comment: @volcano, that is exactly what I have in my answer

Comment: @augurarm it is a sublcass of int as I have  stated in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Break it out and you'll understand it.

```
def does_it_fizz(num):
    return num % 3 == 0

def does_it_buzz(num):
    return num % 5 == 0

for num in range(1, 101):
    print("Fizz" * does_it_fizz(num) + "Buzz" * does_it_buzz(num) or num)
```

String multiplication repeats the string, so `'a' * n` is `aaaaa...n times...a`. if `i % 3 != 0`, then `does_it_fizz(i)` returns `0`. `"any string" * 0 == ""`. If the number should neither Fizz nor Buzz, you get `print("" or num)`. The empty string is Falsey, but `num` is always Truthy, so it prints `num`

Answer (score 1):

When `i == 3`, the `(i % 3 == 0)` will be True.

Any string * True will return the string. It helps to think of `True` as the integer `1` in this case (as anything multiplied by `1` is the original thing that was multiplied).

When eg. `i == 1`, the `(i % 3 == 0)` will be False `(as 1 % 3 == 1)`.

So `string * False` == empty string

Take the fizz and the buzz strings that were returned above and concatenate them using the `+` operator.

Now in the print statement, if the result of that concatenation is an empty string, the `or` operator will use the value of `i` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a breakdown of what is happening:

```
for i in range(1,101):
    if (i % 3 == 0):
        print "Fizz"
    if (i % 5 == 0):
        print "Buzz"
    if (i % 5 != 0 and (i % 3 != 0)):
        print i
```

My ide is set to Python 2.7 btw

Answer (score 1):

If you consider just the conditional:

```
(i % 3 == 0)
```

this generates a boolean which states whether that particular value of i modulo 3 is equal to 0. This is the case for a multiple of 3, or 0 (0, 3, 6, etc). So this is how you would know to print "Fizz" (or "Buzz", given the other conditional).

The cool thing about strings in Python is that you can conditionally print a string. For instance, fire up an interpreter and type this:

```
'foo' * True
'foo' * False
```

This should result in the following output:

```
'foo'
''
```

So basically, for a given value of i, you're doing this:

```
print("Fizz" * (0 % 3 == 0) + "Buzz" * (0 % 5 == 0) or i) -> print("Fizz" * True + "Buzz" * True or i) -> printf('Fizz'+'Buzz')
print("Fizz" * (1 % 3 == 0) + "Buzz" * (1 % 5 == 0) or i) -> print("Fizz" * False + "Buzz" * False or i) -> printf(1)
print("Fizz" * (2 % 3 == 0) + "Buzz" * (2 % 5 == 0) or i) -> print("Fizz" * False + "Buzz" * False or i) -> printf(2)
print("Fizz" * (3 % 3 == 0) + "Buzz" * (3 % 5 == 0) or i) -> print("Fizz" * True + "Buzz" * False or i) -> printf("Fizz")
....
```

This is how the "dank" one liner works.