# What's the best way of distinguishing bools from numbers in Python?

Tags: python

I have an application where I need to be able to distinguish between numbers and bools as quickly as possible. What are the alternatives apart from running `isinstance(value, bool)` first?

Edit:
Thanks for the suggestions. Actually, what I want to be able to do have a check for numbers that leaves out bools so that I can reorder my checks (numbers are far more prevalent) and improve my negacalls. `isinstance()` itself is fast enough. The `x is True or x is False` is intriguing.

Comment: I believe `isinstance(value, bool)` is already idiomatic.

Comment: You don't really have any choices - non-zero numbers will otherwise be evaluated as truth-y, and `isinstance(True, int)` is `True`.

Comment: Alternatively, since bools are exclusively from `[True, False]`, you could do `value is True or value is False`, but I doubt, that it's faster.

Comment: @Boldewyn, it is actually a bit  faster

Comment: @MalikBrahimi No. `True` and `False` are specific instances of the class `bool(int)`. Literal `0` and `1` are instances of `int()`.

Comment: `value.__class__` is faster if you only need to differentiate them.

Comment: _numbers are far more prevalent_ - Could you give an approximate fraction of ints, True, False?

Comment: It's not just ints. I'd say >= 98 % are numbers and the check happens a lot, often many millions of times. The `if x is True or x is False` is probably about as fast is this going to get. There are other limiting factors which become more important with it in place.

Comment: @CharlieClark If there are more `False` than `True` you could reverse the `if` to check `False` first to make it faster, although by what you are saying it will be probably negligible.

Comment: Yes, what I really want is to be able to run isinstance(value, NUMERIC_TYPES) (or equivalent) and to have this return False for bools. The proposed solution does shave some time (about 2 %) from the total which basically means the bottleneck is definitely elsewhere. `isinstance()` generally runs fast enough not to warrant clever optimising.

Comment: @CharlieClark You could use `if x is not True and x is not False` then. It runs about 6 times faster than isinstance() on my pc. Also, i added a corner case which might apply in your data, in the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @user-5061 the boolean short-circuit is, indeed, the fastest approach though your suggestion is logically the same as, though more verbose to the original suggestion. It's a nice trick, indeed and `if` statement is about the fastest thing in Python. Ideally `bool` would be not to be a number in Python, though there are good reasons for this. I guess the optimum would be a dispatch-based approach but I can't see how that would work without an additional function call. Even then it's important to avoid the temptation of micro-optimisations.

Answer (score 5):

So, Padraic Cunningham suggests, that the following might be a bit faster. My own quick experiments with `cProfile`-ing it haven't shown any difference:

```
isbool = value is True or value is False
```

I assume that's as fast as you can get: Two non-type-coercing comparisons.

**Edit:** I replayed the timing tests from @user 5061 and added my statement. This is my result:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> stmt1 = "isinstance(123, bool)"
>>> stmt2 = "123 is True or 123 is False"
>>> t1 = timeit.timeit(stmt1)
>>> t2 = timeit.timeit(stmt2)
>>> print t1
0.172112941742
>>> print t2
0.0690350532532
```

**Edit 2:** Note, that I'm using Python 2.7 here. @user 5061 might use Python 3 (telling from the `print()` function), so any solution provided here should be tested by OP before putting in production, for YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Testing done using Python 3.4.

`stmt5` was suggested by [grc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645956/grc).
`stmt3` was suggested by [boldewyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113195/boldewyn) and seems to be the fastest option in most cases (unless data consists mostly of ints):

```
import timeit

setup = "a = 123; b = True"

stmt1 = "isinstance(a, bool) ; isinstance(b, bool)"
stmt2 = "isinstance(a, int) ; isinstance(b, int)"

stmt3 = "a is True or a is False; b is True or b is False"

stmt4 = "type(a) is bool; type(b) is bool"  
stmt5 = "a.__class__ is bool ; b.__class__ is bool"


repetitions = 10**6
t1 = timeit.timeit(stmt1, setup=setup, number=repetitions)
t2 = timeit.timeit(stmt2, setup=setup, number=repetitions)
t3 = timeit.timeit(stmt3, setup=setup, number=repetitions)
t4 = timeit.timeit(stmt4, setup=setup, number=repetitions)
t5 = timeit.timeit(stmt5, setup=setup, number=repetitions)


print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
print(t4)
print(t5)
```

Results:

```
0.251072
0.190989
0.037483
0.140759
0.08480
```

Note that `isinstance(123, bool)` is slower than `isinstance(123, int)`. Therefore i had to use both `a` and `b`. This is of course assuming that you have an equal amount of ints and bools.

Also, as [grc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645956/grc) suggested in the comments "*True is faster because it short-circuits after the first comparison*", so if you use `b = False` you ll get a slightly slower time for `stmt3`.

---

Only usable if the data does **not** contain `0, 0.0, 1, 1.0`:

```
setup = "a = 123; b = True; s = {True, False}"

stmt3 = "a is True or a is False; b is True or b is False"
stmt6 = "a in s ; b in s"
```

Result:

```
0.037680588
0.03936778
```

If your data consists mostly of integers, this becomes the fastest option (`0.045375` vs `0.0390963`).

Comment: Try `stmt3 = "123 is True or 123 is False=` (basically my answer below). It is yet faster than `stmt2`, because it doesn't create a new list `(True, False)` on each comparison.

Comment: True, it is faster, even though the difference is tiny. I ll edit my post accordingly including other tests soon.

Comment: Cool! If you also have other ideas how to distinguish bools from integers, I'm curious to see how those will do.

Comment: You cannot use in, try `1 in (True, False)`

Comment: Indeed! My Python 2.7 says: `1 in (True, False) is True` This is surprising. :(

Comment: @Boldewyn Perhaps both our answers are flawed. Trying to check if True is bool yields different times. Much different.

Comment: @user5061 `True` is faster because it short-circuits after the first comparison.

Comment: @grc You mean in the `a is True`? Good point, i ll edit accordingly.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Wow! `123 in (True, False)` works fine, would  only `1`s and  `0`s  give True when checked like this? When i first checked what you suggested, i got the impression that any non 0, non empty etc would be considered true with this check.

Comment: Because `True == 1` and `False == 0`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686263/why-does-it-work/28686286#28686286

Comment: @Boldewyn You forgot to edit your post and note that 0 and 1 will give false positives in stmt2.

Comment: @user5061 thanks! I removed the statement completely, since it doesn't work at all for this purpose. The `a.__class_ is bool` was a neat idea to add to the tests, by the way!

Comment: `a.__class__` will be slow because it's a namespace lookup.